# How to pickle os.environ in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

How can I pickle `os.environ` in Python 3?

```
>>> import os, pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(os.environ)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.decode'
```

The above works in Python 2.

Comment: Considering how `os.environ` is supposed to be linked to the actual state of the program's environment variables, it probably wouldn't be a good idea to unpickle one of those anyway. You could pickle and unpickle `dict(os.environ)` easily enough.

Comment: How about converting it to a dictionary? `pickle.dumps(dict(os.environ))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
import os, pickle

pickle.dumps(str(os.environ)) 
pickle.dumps(dict(os.environ))  # this also works
```

Comment: And on unpickling don't replace os.environ — update it: `os.environ.update(pickle.loads(data))`.